# Interchanging const char* and std::string

Tags: c++, stl

I am refactoring an old C library, and am currently changing the external API so that it uses std::string instead of const char*.

```
ColumnType Table::getColType(const char *name) const
{
    int id = getColumnId(name) ;
    return getColType(id) ;
}

and

int Table::getColumnId (const char * col_name) const
{
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while ((i < m_table.num_cols) && (strcmp(m_table.cols[i]->name, col_name) != 0) )
        i++;

    if (i < m_table.num_cols)
        return i;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

To:

```
ColumnType Table::getColType(const std::string& name_in) const
{
    const char* name = name_in.c_str();
    int id = getColumnId(name) ;
    return getColType(id) ;
}

and 

int Table::getColumnId (const std::string& col_name_in) const
{
    const char* col_name = col_name_in.c_str();
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while ((i < m_table.num_cols) && (strcmp(m_table.cols[i]->name, col_name) != 0) )
        i++;

    if (i < m_table.num_cols)
        return i;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

In the new code, I am passing a const char* to functions that are now expecting a reference to const std::string. I know std::string can be initialised from a const char*, and the code compiles correctly (no warnings etc).

But I just want to make sure that I am not doing anything that will come to bite me later on (I18n issues aside).

In short - is what am doing "safe"?

Comment: why pass a `const char*`, and not the `string` itself? The only thing I can think of is that there will be unnecessary copies with each call...

Comment: sadly, C++ objects do not nicely cross library boundries.  Or more specifically, it might fail if the two sides are compiled with different libraries, or by different compilers, or with different settings, or a different time of day...

Comment: @MooingDuck, sure; from his snippet though, looks like the call to `getColumnId` which accepts a `std::string` is passed a `const char*` - a bit redundant really...

Comment: @Nim: My bad, didn't see that.  HomunculusReticulli: Why do you have functions that take strings when you immedately cast them back to `const char*` and then ignore them?  That forces unneeded copies.

Comment: @Nim: Yes, I realized there were extra string copies being made - but I did not want to carryout a wholesale refactoring on 500+ functions. This is a 'first pass' (just dealing with the API), once that's working (which it is), then I intend to clean the internals (like getting rid of the unnecessary string copying etc.

Comment: Be thankful your interface was written in terms of `const char*` and not `char*`

Comment: If  this is a C library why are you using `std::string`?

Comment: @Mooing Duck, That's something to keep in mind on platforms that aren't very careful about ABI compatibility, such as Windows, but if  everyone is careful about ABI compatibility you can be pretty free passing things around, throwing exceptions across (some) boundaries, even deleting things in one module that were new'd in a different one. Although just because one _can_ do this doesn't mean one should.

Comment: @Mooing Duck, Additionally, features like inline namespaces mean that it's safe to mix, for example, libstdc++ and libc++ in the same program. These are ABI incompatible implementations of the standard library, but since the symbols are versioned, if their objects get mixed up you get a link time error instead of strange runtime behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe, in so far as, executed correctly, it shouldn't cause any harm.

Nevertheless, I don't think I would recommend going forward with this unless you can point to a substantial benefit.

What may be safer is to add a function that takes in the const `string&`, and does a straight pass-thru to the `const char*` function.  That way, you're letting clients stay in terms of `std::string&` code without modifying the internals.

For example:

```
ColumnType Table::getColType(const std::string& name_in) const
{
    return getColType(name_in.c_str());
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  External libraries should stick with the most basic/native/simple types on their interfaces (types that can be understood from any language if linked from something you haven't considered yet).  Just look at the hoops .net programmers jump through to make calls to native code that use complex classes/structs as parameters.

Comment: @MartyTPS I think that the guidance you provide is good guidance, but really the problem should dictate the solution.  It is up to the developer to decide whether or not to make the tradeoff between usability/safety and compatibility, and that should depend on the needs of the customer. Just something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

1) No need in getColType to get the c_str() from the std::string, just pass the std::string& directly into getColumnId.

2) You should use the overridden [equality operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/) or use [std::string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)  directly instead of strcmp.  See

Comment: Although, Mooing Duck brings up a good point about std::string compatibility across compiler versions.  I'm not saying you shouldn't do it, but you should understand what all comes with it when you buy into this.

Comment: why `std::string::compare` instead of intuitive `operator==`?

Comment: @AndyT Good point.  I'll add that to the answer, but preserve the compare method as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of `std::string`s containing NULLs. The C++ class is fine with them; NULL is not special. But C strings of course treat it as end-of-string. The The following are *not* the same:

```
if (std_string_a == std_string_b) { /* C++ way */ }

// vs.

const char *cstring_a = std_string_a.c_str(),
           *cstring_b = std_string_b.c_str();
if (0 == strcmp(a, b)) { /* C way */ }
```

When you mix and match, you have to worry about weird bugs arising when the C++ way says false, yet the C way says true.